# Fastest communication between same-machine JVMs

Tags: java, jvm, rmi, pipe

I need to call a method from another JVM running on the same machine. This methods needs to be called very many time with Java/native-like performance. It is a small-input small-output method. The other JVM runs on the same machine.

What is the fastest way to make this call and retrieve the result from this other JVM running "nearby"?

Some options are probably RMI, pipes, sockets, JMS, an optimized same-machine inter-JVM communication support, some low-level hack in the JVM. Any idea is welcome, regardless of how specialized it is.

Comment: JMX is efficient and easy to implement

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way for two JVMs in the same machine to communicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425485/what-is-the-fastest-way-for-two-jvms-in-the-same-machine-to-communicate)

Comment: @Nambari A duplicate question, but I don't agree with the answer. ;)

Comment: @AssenKolov JMX is easy to implement all right, but not even its best friends would call it efficient. A reflective layer over RMI, efficient?

Comment: Thankfully not everyone is a compulsive closer on stackoverflow. I actually got very nice answers.

Comment: @EJP Sure, you are right. I guess I was meaning 'with little development effort', which is just easy, not efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way to communicate between JVMs on the same machine is using shared memory e.g. via memory mapped files.  This is as much as 100x faster than using a Socket over loopback. e.g. a 200 ns round trip time vs a 10-20 micro-second round trip time for Sockets.

One implementation is [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) BTW The 100 ns latency includes persistence of the messages.

Whether you need either of these solutions isn't something you should take for granted.  Often when people say they have to have the "fastest" they really mean they don't know how fast it needs to be so if they pick the fastest it should be the right solution.  This is usually not correct because taking the fastest solution often means making compromises in the design and implementation which it may turn were never needed if only you knew what the requirements really were.

In short, unless you have specific, measurable latency and/or throughput requirements you should assume that the simplest solution is what you really want.  This can be replaced with something faster should it turn out it is not suitable when you have a better understanding of what is required.

Comment: Thanks! 100 times faster than sockets is fast enough. Now to check out the complexities of the implementation. I understand there is some memory mapped support in Java 1.4. JNI is not an option.

Comment: You still need to have a clear idea of your requirements first but since you don't appear to want to do that ;) I have added a link to such a library.

Comment: I need to profile memory-mapped inter-JVM communication myself before I decide what to do next. My requirements are very clear, but I choose not to share them publicy as they are irrelevant and potentially sensitive. Fastest is fastest. If memory mapped is the fastest approach and still does not fit the bill, then inter-JVM communication goes and other options are pursued. I'll check our your library and if it does not use JNI I will use it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It has the option of using JNI or JNA for Thread Affinity to minimize jitter, but that is in a different library and not required.  I often come across projects which have "huge" requirements but when it comes down to it just about any decent solution would have been fine.

Comment: I am curious as to the no JNI requirement given the need to be the fastest.  Why would you rule out JNI?

Comment: Sure. JNI can potentially crash a JVM. Crashes (other than JIT compiler bugs) are intolerable in my setup.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is [0MQ (ZeroMQ)](http://www.zeromq.org/), though it depends what you mean by "fastest" - zeromq is excellent for *throughput* but if you absolutely must have the lowest possible *latency* it may not be optimal.

ZeroMQ may be overkill for just two JVMs, but has the advantage that if you later want to move one of the JVMs to another machine, or communicate with non-Java processes, ZeroMQ will still work just fine - and it scales to larger-scale, more complex communications too.

Comment: So we are talking about huge input/output? That could also be useful. Thanks!

Comment: ZeroMQ has a latency of about 30 micro-seconds round trip. If this latency is ok, it might be better than the alternatives.